# How do I send multiple songs via bluetooth in nokia lumia 620?

Tags: 8.0, bluetooth

When I select the songs from my music library. It then shows only the delete option, not any option for sharing. It shows when I select multiple pictures from my photo album(also able to send multiple pictures via bluetooth.)

Comment: Better to use third party apps

Comment: which third party apps? can suggest any one?

Comment: May be [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/search?q=filemanager) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to send your "musics" to another phone via Bluetooth. (yet)

Comment: Ok, So this is the limitation of windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

open bluetooth and open music player and select the song (please select the longpress and select it) after long press you will get 3 options 1.delete 2.share 3.onedrive now select share and it will give option via bluetooth now you can send your songs

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Files" app. Select all the songs. Press share..Bluetooth and select device.. send

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to share multiple songs at a time. (To share a single song, long-press and select "share"). You can vote for [this](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5142415-transfer-of-multiple-songs-nd-videos-via-bluetooth) feature request if you would like to see this implemented in the future.